# Adding multiple validators in Zend_Form

Tags: zend-framework, validation

I want to create a form field for a login script that allows either a username or an email address to be entered.

I have a validator

```
$loginName = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('loginName');
$loginName->addValidators(array('Alnum', 'EmailAddress');
```

Which does not work (because it seems to validate Alnum AND EmailAddress). I would like to validate Alnum OR EmailAddress.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options.  You can either use a Regex validator, or you can write a custom validator which itself uses the Alnum and Email validators.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.writing_validators.html

The second option would look something like this:

```
    class My_Validate_Field extends Zend_Validate_Abstract
    {
     
        protected $_messageTemplates = array(
            'alnumemail' => "'%value%' is not an alphanumeric string or email address"
        );
     
        public function isValid($value)
        {
              $alnum = new \Zend_Validate_Alnum();
              $email = new \Zend_Validate_EmailAddress();

        $valid = $alnum->isValid( $value ) || $email->isValid( $value);

        if( !$valid ) {
            $this->_error();
        }

            return $valid;
        }
    }
```